# How to Disconnect My Domain Name?

Tags: hosting

So, I have a problem. I recently bought a domain name, as well as a hosting plan. Then I downloaded WordPress and now whenever I want to edit my website, I have to do it by logging in to the "example.com/wp-admin" page.

However, the problem is that I want to be able to make my own website using a FTP (CyberDuck), and not have to use WordPress services. This is my first time doing this, so I'm not sure if my domain name is now connected to WordPress?

If so, how do I disconnect it, so I just have the domain name on its own, and then I can use a FTP to edit the website with HTML/CSS/JS on my own?

I am very confused and not sure what to do.

Comment: http://codex.wordpress.org - I think a Question is not an entire way to enlightenment. Get Codex and get http://google.com first. A site with `example.com/wp-admin` is totally significant to a perfect WordPress installation. If you are not a developer, better hire someone good at it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you need to uninstall WordPress. If your web host includes a hosting control panel then you might have an item called "Quick Install" where you can view your current CMS installations. If you see WordPress listed somewhere you should be able to click a red X and remove it.

If none of that helps then I suggest you call your web host and ask them to walk you through uninstalling WordPress to setup a pure HTML site. They should also be able to walk you through setting up an FTP account so you can begin to upload files.